Old B/W film about kids solving crimes
This was a black-and-white movie, perhaps from the 50s about a group of kids who realise that a gang are communicating through a comic (?) they all read. They go on to catch the gang.
My Dad rang me when I was about 12 yes old (in 1982) to say there was a good film on and that I should watch it. I did, and loved it.

This is Hue And Cry (1947).

A gang of street boys foil a master crook who sends commands for
robberies by cunningly altering a comic strip's wording each week,
unknown to writer and printer. The first of the Ealing comedies.




